# How to match two keywords in AIML?

Tags: pattern-matching, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, aiml

The following **AIML** code is used for keyword detection but it can only detect one key word as it is here the **FAMILY** keyword How can I use such pattern for detecting two keywords in a sentence for example a sentence with **FAMILY** and **FATHER** keyword both included?

```
<category>
  <pattern> FAMILY </pattern>
  <template>
  Family is an important institution.
  </template>
 </category>

<category>
  <pattern> _ FAMILY </pattern>
  <template>
  <srai> FAMILY </srai>
  </template>
 </category>

 <category>
  <pattern> FAMILY * </pattern>
  <template>
  <srai> FAMILY </srai>
  </template>
 </category>

 <category>
  <pattern> _ FAMILY * </pattern>
  <template>
  <srai> FAMILY </srai>
  </template>
 </category>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply :

```
  <pattern> FAMILY * FATHER <pattern>
```

Comment: This will not match a sentence like `I like the father of this family.`

Comment: @AliNfr As I know, you cannot define only one pattern to match 2 words in any position. For two words, you have to define two patterns

    <pattern> FAMILY * FATHER <pattern>
    ...
    <pattern> FATHER * FAMILY <pattern>
    ...

Answer (score 2):

You may simply use multiple keywords and their order like this:

```
    <category>
      <pattern>* FATHER * FAMILY *</pattern>
      <template>
      Family is an important institution.
      </template>
     </category>

   <category>
      <pattern>* FAMILY * FATHER *</pattern>
      <template><srai>* FATHER * FAMILY *</srai> 
      </template>
     </category>
```

This will match all patterns e.g.

1. Father Family
2. SomeText Father SomeText Family
3. Father sometext Family someText
4. etc

Answer (score 0):

You may simply use:

```
<category>
  <pattern>* FAMILY *</pattern>
  <template>
  Family is an important institution.
  </template>
 </category>
```

It would work in following cases:

1. FAMILY
2. some text and FAMILY
3. FAMILY and some text
4. some text FAMILY some text